# Rust 'buffer' does not live long enough compiler error during loop

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and reading "The Book". I'm on chapter 8 and I'm attempting the third exercise recommended at the end of the [chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html).

When compiling the following code I get the error 'buffer' does not live long enough. It looks like the borrow is dropped at line 35 which should be fine since it is the end of the loop, right? Once the loop iterates again a new mutable string is created to borrow from so I do not see the problem.

The compiler is telling me exactly what is going on which is nice and I've reviewed the Referencing and Borrowing section of Chapter 4 but I can't see why this borrow getting dropped is a problem. Any help is very appreciated!

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, io};

fn main() {
    println!("Enter an employee name and department to add that employee to a department.");

    let mut company = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut buffer)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let words: Vec<&str> = buffer.trim().split(" ").collect();

        match words[0].to_lowercase().as_str() {
            "exit" => break,
            "show" => match words[1].to_lowercase().as_str() {
                "company" => println!("Show all employees"),
                "department" => println!("Show all people in {} department", words[1]),
                _ => continue,
            },
            "add" => match words[2].to_lowercase().as_str() {
                "to" => {
                    let employee = words[1];
                    let department = words[3];
                    let hash_department = company.entry(department).or_insert(vec![]);
                    hash_department.push(employee);
                }
                _ => continue,
            },
            _ => continue,
        }
        println!("{:?}", company);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store references to a string which is initialized in a loop, and is dropped every time the loop repeats. You should take ownership of your strings, and pass those around instead, so that the structure which holds them doesn't try to read dropped data. This also needs you to `clone` the data before you store it in the map because you can't move strings out of a `Vec`:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, io};

fn main() {
    println!("Enter an employee name and department to add that employee to a department.");

    let mut company = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut buffer)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let words: Vec<String> = buffer.trim().split(" ").map(|e| e.to_owned()).collect();

        match words[0].to_lowercase().as_str() {
            "exit" => break,
            "show" => match words[1].to_lowercase().as_str() {
                "company" => println!("Show all employees"),
                "department" => println!("Show all people in {} department", words[1]),
                _ => continue,
            },
            "add" => match words[2].to_lowercase().as_str() {
                "to" => {
                    let employee = words[1].clone();
                    let department = words[3].clone();
                    let hash_department = company.entry(department).or_insert(vec![]);
                    hash_department.push(employee);
                }
                _ => continue,
            },
            _ => continue,
        }
        println!("{:?}", company);
    }
}
```

Comment: I never considered that company would still be holding a borrowed value after the loop is done, this definitely helped me grasp the borrowing system a little better. This worked perfectly, thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! I generally try to let any sort of collection own its data because errors like yours are pretty easy to come by.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that your `company` variable has the type `HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>>`, which means it contains borrowed values from your `buffer`. While the `buffer` only lives for one iteration of the loop, the `company` variable is declared and scoped outside of the loop. Therefore, on the second iteration, the code is trying to access a borrowed value from the now dropped `buffer` from the last iteration.

I suggest just copying these values. I doubt you are after the speediest implementation here. It is OK to just copy.